# What is the "query" in Virtual List View control specification?

Tags: java, ldap, ldap-query, unboundid-ldap-sdk, virtuallistview

I am reading [Virtual List View control specification](https://docs.ldap.com/specs/draft-ietf-ldapext-ldapv3-vlv-09.txt)

and there is the phrase

> contextID values have no validity outside     the connection and query
> with which they were received. A client MUST     NOT submit a
> contextID which it received from a different connection,     a
> different query, or a different server.

I use unboundId library:

```
public SearchRequest(@NotNull final String baseDN,
                     @NotNull final SearchScope scope,
                     @NotNull final Filter filter,
                     @Nullable final String... attributes)
```

If I have 2 `SearchRequest`s which are different only in attributes. Will it mean that query are different or not?

Answer (score 0):

The SearchRequests will be different.

I am not clear what you are needing to determine.

As stated it is:

> A server-generated contextID MAY be returned to clients. A client
> receiving a contextID **MUST** return it unchanged or not return it at
> all, in a subsequent request which relates to the same list. The
> purpose of this interaction is to maintain state information between
> the client and server

Also, [unboundid-ldap-sdk is extremely well documented and often with Examples](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/controls/VirtualListViewRequestControl.html).
Set it like:

```
 ASN1OctetString vlvContextID = null;
```

And include it with any subsequent request which relates to the same list.

A searchRequest is presented to the LDAP Server and you receive a searchResponse.

A "filter" is is part of the searchRequest and might be like:

```
"dc=example,dc=com"
```

Again, there are [examples for searchRequest](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/SearchRequest.html).

LDAP Query is an abstract term that requires an agreed upon connotation.

Most people probably relate LDAP Query to the collection of LDAP Filter parameters and LDAP Operators: (&(objectClass=user)(sn=Smith))

A [searchRequest](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/SearchRequest.html) contains 10-11 items which could affect the [searchResult](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/SearchResultEntry.html) even if the [Filter](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/Filter.html) is the same.

Comment: I want to understand difference between "query" and "SearchRequest". Could I consider them as the same ?

Comment: Did you get nt question ?

Comment: An LDAP query is a more general term referring to the act of querying an LDAP directory.

while a SearchRequest is a specific type of LDAP operation used to initiate a search within the directory. 

An example of a collection of LDAP Filter parameters and LDAP Operators:
(&(objectClass=user)(sn=Smith))

Comment: So if I create 2 SearchRequests instances with the same filter and the Ldap operators but with different attributes according to documentaion it will be the same query. Correct ?